# Express redirect subdomain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, express

Using `npm subdomain` I have routes on my server like `/subdomain/app` which can proxy `app.localhost` and send requests.

On my client side I am trying to think of ways to keep the path relative, so when switching between production and development I don't have to change the link.

I am thinking of adding a correlating link to `/subdomain/app` like `/sub_Domain/app` to create the relative path on the client, then inside express route `/sub_Domain/app` responding with the proper url in this case will return `app.localhost`, then back on the client redirect to that with javascript?

**Example:**

```
//client
<a href="/sub_Domain/app">Go to app</a>

//server
router.get('/sub_Domain/app', function(req,res) {
  // added res.headers.origin to adapt if local or production
  res.send('app.'+res.headers.origin);
}
```

Then maybe I would have to prevent the default link and sit there to wait for a response then redirect according to said response.

I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this? What are my options etc?

Comment: what do you want to do??

Comment: inside my a tag link to `/sub_domain/app` on my express end `sub_domain/app` listens to that changing the url to `app.localhost`. Using npm subdomain `app.localhost` responds to `/subdomain/app` as a proxy.